# How Does the $.getJSON success function Works

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have php outputting a  JSON Messages in this manner  when the Wrong information is incorrect
`{"error":"Wrongparameter"}{"seatno":"8989"}`.So the Wrong info can be shown 
on the Jquery Modal. "message" is nothing but the php exception caught.

This Message Comes when all the Correect Information has been entered and Seat number is generated

```
{"seatno":"8989"}

$.getJSON("test.php?cde="+code,
                        $("#form1").serialize(),                        
                        function(data){ 
                            alert("Inside");                        
                            $('#dialog1').dialog('close');                                                                                      
                            if ( data.seat != null )
                            {
                                //Do Some Processing.                               
                            }else{
                                $("#div1").removeAttr('style');
                                $("#div1").text("Error" + data.error);
                            }                           
                         });
```

does the Anonymous $getJson()  function work only when the Correct data is genretaed . I am not able to get the "error" generated in json  into The Dialog which is in else part

Comment: You're missing a `'` in `$('#dialog1).dialog('close');`: it should be `$('#dialog1').dialog('close');`

Comment: How do you return your data in PHP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use another format in your response, something more like:

```
{ 'error': 'Wrongparameter', 'seatno': '8989' }
```

The problem is that you're trying to access `data` as a single object, but you're returning 2 objects in the response.